# How to use px and % in the same layout like this

Tags: css

I have searched for this question, but I can't find a good solution, so maybe you guys can help me.

[Link](http://www.247solitaire.com/)

If you look at this site, you can see that in each side (left/right), there is a banner. The width for these two are 160px each. the website is using the WHOLE screen at any givin time, but the ads are still 160px no matter what, and the game in the middle is the one shrinking to fit the screen, both vertically and horisontally.

How can I achieve this, and is it even possible to do in css alone? I've looked their code, but I can't really figure it out.

Comment: I don't see the banners you describe on that site. Anyway, the site itself is done in Flash.

Comment: Have you tried searching for some CSS layout tutorials?

Comment: @Morten You should change the tags on this question from [css] to [flash], as the question is not CSS related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banner provided by thirt pars (like AdSense) can't generally be resized for an obvoius reason: the advertiser provides, one or more images for the banner, possibly of different sizes; but that sizes **are generally not intended to be "scalable"** 'cause in that case the result might suck...

You can scale the container, of course, but you are asking about ADS...

Comment: It's not the banners I want to change. It's the "game" like on the site. If you rescale your browser the game will vertically and horisontally "follow""